# Flatten object to array?

Tags: javascript

I'm using an object as a hash table. I'd like to quickly print out its contents (for `alert()` for instance). Is there anything built in to convert a hash into arrays of (key, value) pairs?

Comment: what wrong with `console.log` or `console.dir` ?

Comment: What's wrong with console.log()? Why alert? It never shows enough debugging info. Consoles of newer browsers should display sufficient info if you console.log your variable. Also, JS arrays are objects.. or if you will, objects are associative arrays.

Comment: @N.B.: JS `Array`s are `Object`s; and JS `Object`s model the concept of "associative arrays", but "associative arrays" and `Array`s are distinct notions. Let's not confuse them! The OP's terminology is spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated this some more. This is much easier to parse than even console.log because it leaves out the extra stuff that's in there like `__proto__`.

```
function flatten(obj) {
    var empty = true;
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        str = '[';
        empty = true;
        for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
            empty = false;
            str += flatten(obj[i])+', ';
        }
        return (empty?str:str.slice(0,-2))+']';
    } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
        str = '{';
        empty = true;
        for (i in obj) {
            empty = false;
            str += i+'->'+flatten(obj[i])+', ';
        }
        return (empty?str:str.slice(0,-2))+'}';
    } else {
        return obj; // not an obj, don't stringify me
    }
}
```

The only thing I would do to improve this is have it indent correctly based on recursion level.

Comment: Why would you choose this over `console.log`? Why are you eschewing the fantastic debugging options that your browser provides for you?

Comment: Who said anyone was eschewing `console.log`? The question was how to flatten data. `alert()` was only mentioned "for instance". What if he wants to send it back to a server via Ajax to be logged there?

Comment: I am aware of `console.log` and it is certainly great for most of my debugging needs. However sometimes I find it useful to use the alert to find out exactly when something happens. The code that comes directly after an alert does not get executed until you OK the alert. Generally when this behavior isn't desired there is little reason to use `alert()`.

Comment: Also iOS5 is pretty terrible about letting you see all of the log string.

Comment: ...And iOS6 requires you to have a Mac (!) *and* an appropriate USB cable (!!) in order to see your console.logs. *shakes fist*

Answer (score 11):

Since you want to `alert` it out I assume it's not for your production version, and that old browser compatibility is not an issue.

If this is the case, then you can do this:

```
var myHash = ......
alert(Object.keys(myHash).map(function(key) { return [key, myHash[key]]; }));
```

Comment: Oh, yes it is:

    `var myUsers = {};`

    `myUsers[0] = {'id': 'x', 'username': 'aaa'}\n`
    `myUsers[1] = {'id': 'y', 'username': 'bbb'}`
    `Object.keys(myUsers).map(function(key) { return myUsers[key].username; })`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

for quick & dirty use in `alert` you could use `JSON`:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(yourObj).replace(/,/g,'\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. Still, you can do it yourself fairly concisely:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var arr = [];
for (var i in obj) {
   var e = {};
   e[i] = obj[i];
   arr.push(e);
}
console.log(arr);
// Output: [Object { a=1 }, Object { b=2 }, Object { c=3 }]
```

Of course, you can't `alert` this either, so you might as well just `console.log(obj)` in the first place.

---

You *could* output arrays of arrays:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var arr = [];
for (var i in obj) {
   arr.push([i, obj[i]]);
}
console.log(arr);
// Output: [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]

alert(arr);
// Alert: a, 1, b, 2, c, 3
```

But, again, ew.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of it. It should allow you to flatten input like below:

```
var input = {
   a: 'asdf',
   b: [1,2,3],
   c: [[1,2],[3,4]],
   d: {subA: [1,2]}
}
```

The function is like this:

```
    function flatten (input, output) {

      if (isArray(input)) {
        for(var index = 0, length = input.length; index < length; index++){
          flatten(input[index], output);
        }
      }
      else if (isObject(input)) {
        for(var item in input){
          if(input.hasOwnProperty(item)){
            flatten(input[item], output);
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        return output.push(input);
      }
    };

    function isArray(obj) {
      return Array.isArray(obj) || obj.toString() === '[object Array]';
    }

    function isObject(obj) {
      return obj === Object(obj);
    }
```

Usage is something like:

var output = []

flatten(input, output);

Then output should be the flattened array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but here you have my version of the answer, updated to ES2015. I use a recursive function and it works even if there are other objects inside the main object:

```
function objectFlattener (object) {
  return Reflect.apply(Array.prototype.concat, [], Object.keys(object).map(key => {
    if (object[key] instanceof Object) {
      return objectFlattener(object[key]);
    }
    return `${ key }: ${ object[key] }`;
  }));
}
```

So changing the last return you can format the element inside your array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the for loop:

```
for (var x in yourObj)
{
    alert(yourObj[x]);
}
```

Comment: that way you would only see the values. Bute even if you concentenate the keys too, it would alert many many times probably. You should create one string and alert the final output.

Comment: well this is just an example of the for loop, not a complete implementation of what the op wants. he should be able to figure the rest out.