# Flatten nested object’s keys into an array, with JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, nested

I have an object, and I’d like to get each “branch” of the “tree” as an array. (Feel free to correct my terminology also!) What I have is like the following:

```
var features = {
  "f": {
    "t": "100",
    "f": {
      "i": ['150'],
      "b": ['300'],
      "f": {
        "k": 100
      }
    },
    "l": ['255']
  },
  "c": {
    "s": {
      "t": ["100"]
    },
    "t": "100"
  }
};
```

And I’d like to parse it into the following result, so I can iterate over it again and pass it into another function.

```
var result = [
  "ffi",
  "fffk",
  "fl",
  "ct"
]
```

What I have so far [is on JS Bin here](http://jsbin.com/xayexeve/17/edit?js,console). Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten object to array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660765/flatten-object-to-array)

Comment: @Nit I don’t think so, I am just looking for the keys, in a way that retains the entire branch. I appreciate the link, though, it might still be helpful for getting to the end result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [un-flatten-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/un-flatten-tree) npm module to convert the tree into the list of branches. Also note that 'map' from [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) is used for object traversal.

```
function walk(tree) {
    return _.map(tree, function (v, k) {
        return {
            name: k,
            items: (typeof v !== 'object' || v instanceof Array) ? [] : walk(v)
        };
    });
}

function getChildNodes(node) {
    return node.items.map(function (item) {
        return {
            name: node.name + item.name,
            items: item.items
        };
    });
}

var result = uft.flatten(walk(features), getChildNodes)
    .filter(function (node) { return node.items.length === 0; })
    .map(function (node) { return node.name; });
```

**Live example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/iyegoroff/ut3bz6oc/