# Count deeply nested object properties of type 'String'

Tags: javascript

How to get nested string with help of recursion when it is in the array that is in the object?

```
 function getStringCount(arr) {
  let res = 0;
  Object.values(arr).forEach((item)=> {
    if(typeof item === 'string') {
      res++;
    } else if(item =) {
      res+= getStringCount(item);
    } 
  })
  return res;
}


console.log(getStringCount({
  first: '1',
  second: '2',
  third: false,
  psd:[{foo:[{fooo:'23'}]}]
}))
```

Comment: I think this could help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660765/flatten-object-to-array . As well you all ready have the solution the just remove the = from the else if (item = ). Unless this is something that you defensively need to achieve recursively I could suggest to just avoid recursion. Flatten the data and then iterate the array

Answer (score 1):

If that's about counting all (including nested) object values of type `String`, you may do the following:

```js
const src = {first:'1',second:'2',third:false,psd:[{foo:[{fooo:'23'}]}]},

      countStringTypes = o =>
        Object
          .keys(o)
          .reduce((r,key) =>      
            r += o[key] && typeof o[key] == 'object' ? 
            countStringTypes(o[key]) : 
            typeof o[key] == 'string' ?
            1 :
            0, 0)
          
console.log(countStringTypes(src))
```

Looks, like it passes all the quick tests right off the top of my head:

```js
mocha.setup('bdd')

const { expect } = chai

const countStringTypes = o =>
            Object
              .keys(o)
              .reduce((r,key) =>      
                r += o[key] && typeof o[key] == 'object' ? 
                countStringTypes(o[key]) : 
                typeof o[key] == 'string' ?
                1 :
                0
              , 0),
      testSuite = [
       {
        input: {},
        output: 0,
        descr: 'Should handle properly empty object'
       },
       {
        input: {a: null, b: true, c: 'false', d: '1'},
        output: 2,
        descr: 'Should work for flat objects'
       },
       {
        input: {a: true, b:{c: '1', d: {f: ['str', {g: 'h'}]}}},
        output: 3,
        descr: 'Should work for deeply nested props'
       },
      ]

describe('Basic tests to count string-type values within object', ()=>{
  testSuite.forEach(({input, output, descr}) => 
    it(descr, ()=>{
        expect(countStringTypes(input)).to.deep.equal(output)
    }))
})

mocha.run()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/8.0.1/mocha.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script><div id="mocha"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `else if(Array.isArray(item))`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, with the help of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
You can call [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on every value that is not a string to get its properties, if any.

```js
const getStringCount = (count, value) => {

  if (typeof value === 'string') return count + 1;

  return Object.values(value).reduce(getStringCount, count);
};

const testObject = {
  first: '1',
  second: '2',
  third: false,
  fourth: {},
  psd: [{
    foo: [{
      fooo: '23',
    }],
  }],
};

const result = getStringCount(0, testObject);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) can be used for an easy way to check or modify all nested keys and values :

```js
function getStringCount(obj) {
  let res = 0;
  JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => typeof v === 'string' ? res++ : v); 
  return res;
}

console.log(getStringCount({ first: '1', second: '2', third: false,
                             psd: [{ foo: [{ fooo: '23' }] }] }));
```